# Converted OBJ to SCN and now the object won't load

Tags: 3d, scenekit, scnnode

```swift
let pathToBalloon = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "./Balloon2", ofType: "scn")!
    let balloonAsset = MDLAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToBalloon))
    let balloonObject: MDLObject? = balloonAsset.object(at: 0)
    let balloon = SCNNode(mdlObject: balloonObject!) // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Using an .obj file with a balloon works great and displays in SCNView just fine.
To use extra features Xcode asked me to convert to a .scn format.
The model loads just fine in the Xcode editor, however `balloonAsset.object(at: 0)` now returns nil.

I really wanted to smooth the geometry and other stuff so continuing to use .obj files is meh.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model I/O does not support opening SceneKit files (see [file formats supported by the Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset/asset_file_types)).

Instead you should use SceneKit's `+[SCNScene sceneNamed:]` or `+sceneWithURL:options:error:`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked: let balloonScene = try! SCNScene(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToBalloon))
        balloon = balloonScene.rootNode.childNodes.first!